# Windows forms application to access google firestore, through proxy internet. How can i do that?

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-firestore

I want my Windows forms application to access google firestore, through proxy internet. How can i do that ??

In my windows forms application, i am able to insert & delete data in google firestore database when i run this code connected to broadband internet.

But in my office internet is available through proxy internet.
How can i make my below mentioned code work through proxy internet.

I am using following APIs
1. Google.Cloud.Storage.V1;
2. Google.Cloud.Firestore;

```
private async Task InsertData(string project, Dictionary<string, object> user, String empid)
        {
            FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create(project);
            DocumentReference docRef = db.Collection("employees").Document(empid);
            label1.Text += "Inserting Data to  Google Firestore........ \n";
            WriteResult x = await docRef.SetAsync(user);
            label1.Text += "Data Inserted successfully for EmpNo :- "+empid+ "\n";

        }
```

I want my application to access google firestore application through proxy internet with minimum changes in my code.